# How to get the root error of any function that uses PySpark in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, pyspark

I'm trying to get the location of the root error if an error occurs when calling a function.
For ex:

```
class SomeClass:
    def some_fn(self):
        # line of error in code I want location of

def some_other_fn():
    obj = SomeClass()
    obj.some_fn() # error given on this line
```

I tried using:

```
exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
file = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
print(f"\nAn error occurred of type !{exc_type}!, in file !{file}!, at line no. !{exc_tb.tb_lineno}!")
```

But it returns the location where the function is called. I want the location of the actual error. How can I do this? I have made program with packages and I'm using Spark for all the processes. Below is a sample snippet of my code:

```
        if df.rdd.count() != 0:
            fn1(spark)
            fn2(spark)
        else:
            break
```

I have used try and except in every function which sends a mail if an error occurs. So when I kill the spark session, all the exceptions in the all the functions fire up and send out mails as Spark only gives Py4jJavaError mostly. How do I get only the root error of the Spark exception in that specific file?

Note that I am using PySpark 2.3, so can't make use of PySpark 3 features.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I tried using traceback but it also shows the error at line where the function is called. I want the line where the actual error is, i.e. inside the function.

Comment: It shows *the whole stack trace*. It should show everything, it's pretty much as useful as it gets, is there a reason you don't want the whole stack trace?

Comment: I'm trying to get the error via smtp mail. Earlier I was using traceback.format_exec() but it would be nice if I got only the actual error only without details as they get store in the log file.

Comment: I think your question maybe specific to PySpark? If that is the case, I think that maybe causing some of the confusing contributors are having and you should reword the title to be more specific.

Comment: @Chris Yeah I thought so but I also thought that might happen in normal Python program as well so I didn't add Spark details first.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the top of the stack, you can extract that info with the `traceback` module, something like:

```
import traceback

tb = traceback.extract_tb(exc_tb)
summary = tb[-1]
print(f"\nAn error occurred of type !{exc_type}!, in file !{summary.filename}!, at line no. !{summary.lineno}!")
```

You also have access to:

```
print(summary.line)
```

Comment: I tried this but the error is showing as None and the filename is not what I want. It's giving me this file name /usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py

Comment: @VarunNagrare that doesn't make any sense. Why would the error be `None` now? Was it showing `None` before when you were printing `exc_type`?

Comment: @VarunNagrare you really need to provide an example we can work with. I don't know why the error is printing as `None`, but I suspct that the *ultimate root of the error* is coming from ` /usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py`. What *exactly is the error produced by `obj.some_fn()`*? Print the stack trace for us

Comment: See the whole scenario is that, I have made a program with packages using Spark, and when I kill the Spark Session, all the exceptions in all the modules fire up and send out mails. So I'm trying to get only the specific location where the error has occurred. I was comfortable with the traceback.format_exec() but as all the exceptions are fired at once, I'm trying to change it.

Comment: @VarunNagrare I'm not really understanding what you are saying. But that should give you the source of the error. It's not going to automatically stop at the code you wrote personally.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, it prints the exc_type in terminal but on mail it shows up None.

Comment: @VarunNagrare you need to provide more information about what you are exactly doing.

Comment: I edited the question now. I think it's mostly related to Spark but can occur in normal Python program also so I didn't go in the details of Spark.

Answer (score 0):

A PySpark Python application eventually calls out to core Spark running on the JVM. Any exceptions raised on the JVM are caught and converted into an appropriate Python exception by `pyspark.sql.utils.convert_exception` (PySpark 3). You can see the full list of exceptions if you take a look at that function. It also appends a `cause` if there is one in the Scala exception.

You can catch the exception in your application code and either log the cause, or the exception itself, depending on whether `cause` is `None`.

Comment: Yes that's what the problem is. It gives a generic Py4jJavaError and that causes the mail part of my program to run in all the functions. How can I avoid it and just get a single mail for the specific error and not from all the functions?

Comment: I guess you would need to parse the traceback and pick the last entry that refers to your application code (before it goes off into the PySpark code).

Comment: @Varun Nagrare does this updated answer help?

Comment: Hey hi sorry had been busy. Btw thanks for helping but it didn't solve my issue. I made some changes in my code now and for time being the problem is solved but I'd like to know if we can handle a specific error in pyspark like if I get an AnalysisException, it shows up in Py4jJavaError but I'd like to get that specific error name to handle it properly. Is there any way to handle the java side errors like org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException in python?

Comment: Ah, so I was wrong. At least in pySpark 3 the Java exception is wrapped in a python AnalysisException as you say. You can catch that. If cause field is None then the exception itself is the root cause, otherwise, In some circumstances the cause field will provide the root cause exception. Does that help?

Comment: Yeah I can catch other exceptions as there are specific Python alternatives to some exceptions but this particular exception called SparkException. I can't find this exception or it's alternative in PySpark. I read the py4j.protocol.Py4jJavaError with the help function, and saw that we can get the java side exception by using e.java_exception but how can I handle this specific SparkException, I can't figure it out.

Comment: Also I can't find this convert_exception in pysaprk.sql.utils but there is a capture_sql_exception

Comment: It is there in PySpark 3. Maybe you have an older version.

Comment: Yeah just checked, it's PySpark 2.3 and I'm bound to use it as it's on production server. Anyways thanks!